# Angularjs: Dynamically created controllers are doubled

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-controller

I´m trying to dynamically create childControllers within a masterController. I got the idea from [this page](http://peter.grman.at/dynamic-controllers-in-angularjs/). Please see this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fs3g9vem/4/) and watch the console.

The + creates a new childController. Each childController has a random number, created in its controller function, and a number set by ng-init.

When I do the following:

```
click the +
click Emit
click BroadCast
```

the console output is:

```
new masterController

creating new childController..
new childController (undefined : 37818)
created the new childController
new childController (undefined : 49443)

child (0 : 49443) emitting..
masterController heard (0:49443)

broadcasting..
(undefined : 37818) received the broadcast
(0 : 49443) received the broadcast
done broadcasting
```

Here is becomes clear that two childControllers are generated, instead of just one. If I remove html-line 16

```
ng-controller="childController"
```

then only one controller is created, so I assume the problem is that this line creates another controller. How do I circumvent this, and am I correctly creating controllers dynamically?

Comment: Please [edit] in the relevant code as text in your post.  External links are no substitute for code in the post itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct in your assumption that ng-controller was creating another controller. To bypass this, you can pass it the controller constructor instead of instantiating it yourself.

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/acw9q0ya/

In `createNewChildController`:

```
    var ControllerFn = function() {
        return $controller('childController', { $scope: $scope.$new() }).constructor;
    };
    $scope.childControllers.push(ControllerFn)
```

Lastly in the ng-repeat, the name passed needs to match what was passed into `$controller`.

```
<div ...
  ng-repeat="childController in childControllers" 
  ng-controller="childController"
  ...
>
```

Comment: This makes sense. Could you explain why you use a function that returns a controller, instead of just pushing it into the array like push($controller('childController', { $scope: $scope.$new() }).constructor)?

Comment: From Angular's $controller docs: If called with a function then it's considered to be the controller constructor function. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$controller This is also the way it's done on the page you linked in your question

Comment: Ah of course! I was confusing ControllerFn and ControllerFn(). One final question if you don't mind. I also need to remove childControllers. Is there some way to know where a child is located in the array? I could give each child a unique ID and use that as a key, but I'd rather do it a more formal way.

Comment: I'd be happy to help, but you should post your question as a new question.

Answer (score 1):

ng-repeat creates the controller itself. There's no need for you to create the controller. Replace your code with this:

```
$scope.createNewChildController = function(){
        console.log("\ncreating new childController..")
        //var Controller = $controller('childController', { $scope: $scope.$new() });
        $scope.childControllers.push({})
        console.log("created the new childController")
    }
```

If you want to use a dynamic controller like the example you want, keep in mind that you will have to have a variable for each item in the array:

```
$scope.SubController_1 = function() {
  return $controller('ControllerName', { $scope: $scope.$new() }).constructor;
};
```